# A r.s. of size n is taken from a normal r.v. X~N(μ, 1.5). To be 95% confident that the error between X̄ and μ is at most .85, how large must n be?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Suppose a random sample of size *n* is taken from a normal random variable *X~N(μ, 1.5)*. To be 95% confident that the error between X̄ and the unknown population mean μ is at most .85, how large of a sample needs to be taken?

Does this mean that the confidence itnerval is of size .85*2?

I know what the formulas are for a confidence interval for the mean, but I don't know where to start with this one.

Answer (score 0):

$\bar{X}$ is distributed like a $N(\mu, 1.5 / n)$ (the way to think clearly about this is to remember that adding independent normals [adds their means and variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables), and scaling a random variable by $\lambda$ multiplies its variance by $\lambda^2$).

You can translate everything by $-\mu$.

Therefore, you want to choose $n$ so that the $P( A_n \in [ - .85, .85]) \geq .95$, where $A_n \sim N(0, 1.5/n)$. ($A_n$ is the distribution of $\bar{X}$ when taking $n$ samples.)

From the [$68-95-99.7$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) rule, you basically want $.85$ to be 2 standard deviations - now, the standard deviation of $A_N$ is $\sqrt{1.5/n}$...

(You can compute it more exactly also.)

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, the desired margin of error, $$0.85 = \text{ME} = z_{\alpha/2}^* \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},$$ or equivalently, $$n = \left(\frac{z_{\alpha/2}^* \sigma}{\text{ME}}\right)^{\!2},$$ where $z_{\alpha/2}^*$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ quantile of the standard normal distribution, which for a $95\%$ confidence interval corresponds to $\alpha = 0.05$ and $z_{.025}^* \approx 1.96$; $\sigma = 1.5$ is the population standard deviation, and $n$ is the sample size.  The rest is simply substitution and calculation.  Note that if the result is not an integer, one must round *up* to the nearest integer.